# Event is not called in lightning

Tags: lightning

I have two components in which once have aura:registerEvent and other aura:handler. But when I use the component that containing aura:registerEvent which is having button in lightning app, Event is not getting called.

```
<!-- ---c:TestEvent1--------- -->
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="messageFromEvent" type="String"/>

    <aura:handler name="TestEvent" event="c:TestEvent" action=" {!c.handleComponentEvent}"/>

    <p>{!v.messageFromEvent}</p>

    </aura:component>

 <!-- ---c:TestEvent2--------- -->
  <aura:component >
      <aura:registerEvent name="TestEvent" type="c:TestEvent"/>
       <p><ui:button
         label="Click here"
         press="{!c.fireComponentEvent}" />
       </p>
     <c:TestEvent1/>
  </aura:component>
```

In my app i am using     "c:TestEvent2"

Comment: Add your code, please.

Comment: Would like to see the corresponding JS controllers & the event definition as well.